# how to DRY polymorphic activerecord classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionresult

i have a bunch of activerecord classes that look way to similar for my liking!

can I extend a base class to DRY the methods up, or is that going to confuse rails?

maybe i can share some stuff but not others?

if not - what's the best way to proceed?

many thanks ;)

```
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  has_many :services, :as => :serviceable
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user

  after_save :tag!

  def t(s)
    self.tag_list.add s
    self.event.tag_list.add s
  end

  # injected to after_save -> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html
  def tag!
    s = self

      if s.id > 0 then s.t "id-greater-than-0" end
      if s.id > 0 then s.t "some-stage-specific-stuff" end

    self.tag_list    
  end
end



class Sound < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  has_many :services, :as => :serviceable
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user

  after_save :tag!

  def t(s)
    self.tag_list.add s
    self.event.tag_list.add s
  end

  # injected to after_save -> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html
  def tag!
    s = self

      if s.id > 0 then s.t "some-sound-specific-stuff" end

    self.tag_list    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Single Table Inheritance for this problem. Essentially you will have two separate models, but they'll be saved in the same table. Along with that you can extract out the common functionality into a parent class, and leave the specifics for the child classes. You can read more about STI here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance